# How to implement char pointers in a node structure?

Tags: c, insert, nodes

I'm a little confused as to how to go about implementing the char pointer found in the arguments of the insert function. This function was made without the char *c argument but I realized I need to include it as the structure has a string name field (up to 25 characters long).

I hope I explained well enough... I want to understand where it is I would include the code for addition of the name in this function:

```
struct data_node * insert(struct data_node **p_first, int elem, char *c) {

struct data_node *new_node, *prev, *current;
current=*p_first;
while (current != NULL && elem > current->data) {
   prev=current;
   current=current->next;
} /* end while */
/* current now points to position *before* which we need to insert */
new_node = (struct data_node *) malloc(sizeof(struct data_node));
new_node->data=elem;

new_node->next=current;
if ( current == *p_first ) /* insert before 1st element */
   *p_first=new_node; 
else                       /* now insert before current */
   prev->next=new_node;
/* end if current == *p_first */
return new_node;
}; /* end insert */
```

struct data_node:

```
#define STRINGMAX 25

struct data_node {
   char name [STRINGMAX];
   int data;
   struct data_node *next;
   };
```

Comment: What's the definition of `struct data_node`?

Comment: added the struct code for data_node

Comment: Don't you need a strcpy(new_node->name,c);  ??  (or strncpy)

Comment: After `new_node->data=elem;`, I imagine you want to insert `strncpy(new_node->name, c, STRINGMAX);`

Also, you probably want `const char *c` instead of just `char *c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `name` when you're initializing the rest.

```
new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct data_node));
new_node->data=elem;
strncpy(new_node->name, name, STRINGMAX);
```

Comment: To insure `new_node->name` is `'\0'` terminated, code could use `strncpy(new_node->name, name, STRINGMAX-1); new_node->name[STRINGMAX-1] = '\0'`.

Comment: check for a failure of the call to malloc() before setting any fields of the new node.